# Can't import custom module with require() in Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Here's a simplified code example for what I'm doing.

foo.js (in lib directory):

```
exports.foo = function foo() {
    this.bar = function() {
        console.log("foobar!");
    };
};
```

main.js:

```
var foo = require("foo");
exports.main = function(options, callbacks) {
    foo.bar();
}
```

cmd:

```
>cfx run
[...]
error: An exception occurred.
[...]
TypeError: foo.bar is not a function
```

So basically, I can't seem to do anything with the module I've imported. Am I doing something wrong here? I've tried formatting the foo() function in a few different ways and none of them seem to be able to do anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of the `require()` function is essentially the `exports` variable of the module - and you didn't define `exports.bar`. So either you call `foo.foo.bar()` in your `main.js` or you import the module slightly differently:

```
var {foo} = require("foo");
```

This is the same as:

```
var foo = require("foo").foo;
```

Also, as erikvold notes in his answer, you didn't really define `exports.foo.bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var foo = exports.foo = function foo() {
};

foo.bar = function() {
    console.log("foobar!");
};
```

Your example wouldn't work in any context.